# Puppeteer not working in the google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, puppeteer

I have built one project in node js. that create a pdf using puppeteer after submitting some from the HTML form. Everything is working fine in localhost. But, pdf in generating in google app engine environment after deploy. This project is on my github profile. [Project on Github](https://github.com/akshaykalola28/mandali-annexure)

Comment: Could you please  provide some further information, such as: the error you are facing, your application's package.json which includes your dependencies, your app.yaml file so we can clarify the issue? Additionally, keep in mind the link you have provided is not working. [Here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1036) and [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-run-pyppeteer-on-google-app-engine-flex-or-how-i-lost-it-trying-701b09fadf99) you might find any useful information.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

puppeteer will not work same as expected with google app engine standard environment. You can use a flexible environment with Docker to work as expected. Or you can also use a compute engine with your own configurations.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it on App Engine, it was quite simple in the end. I have it running like this:

package.json has puppeteer in dependencies:

```
"puppeteer": "^21.0.0"
```

You need a puppeteer config file in the root of your project as well (eg 'puppeteer.config.js'):

```
const { join } = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

App.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs16
instance_class: F4
```

Code that launches puppeteer:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: 'new',
      args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    });
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly this (although we are using nodejs20) and I get 
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 116.0.5845.96). This can occur if either
1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /workspace/.cache/puppeteer).

Comment: @CoreyH I think I remember I had that error before I set the cacheDirectory in the config

Comment: @CoreyH I have the same issue with node18 and with the conf file. Did you make it work?

Comment: @httpete strange - I redeployed just now setting my runtime to nodejs18 and it's running fine.
I wonder if your config file is not getting picked up or something?
Just trying to think of other things that might be different - I'm using app engine standard environment rather than flex (just in case that's useful).

Answer (score -1):

Running Puppeteer on GCP is supported now with App engine and Cloud Functions.

**Running Puppeteer on Google App Engine**

The Node.js runtime of the App Engine standard environment comes with all system packages needed to run Headless Chrome.

To use puppeteer, simply list the module as a dependency in your package.json and deploy to Google App Engine. Read more about using puppeteer on App Engine by following the official tutorial.

**Running Puppeteer on Google Cloud Functions**

The Node.js 10 runtime of Google Cloud Functions comes with all system packages needed to run Headless Chrome.

To use puppeteer, simply list the module as a dependency in your package.json and deploy your function to Google Cloud Functions using the nodejs10 runtime.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/troubleshooting#running_puppeteer_in_the_cloud