# Puppeteer not working in Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, puppeteer

```
error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so cannot open shared object file
```

I want to deploy my puppeteer app on google app engine since it says their node.js environment supports the puppeteer however
I get still get this error.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Hi @user17399782, although my answer should help you to fix the error, please consider editting your question including a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer requires custom libraries, so you need to make sure you are using the custom environment in your `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: custom env: flex
```

You can find a similar issue in this [Github thread](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6654).

You also need to check the App Engine [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) for your language that describes dependencies specification to make sure your steps are aligned with the guidelines.

If you are using the [App Engine Standard environment](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/troubleshooting#running_puppeteer_on_google_app_engine), the Node.js runtime of the App Engine standard environment comes with all system packages needed to run Headless Chrome.

To use `puppeteer`, simply list the module as a dependency in your `package.json` and deploy to Google App Engine. Read more about using puppeteer on App Engine by following the [official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-headless-chrome-with-puppeteer).

Answer (score 0):

I added an answer to this question which you might find useful:

[Puppeteer not working in the google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548124/puppeteer-not-working-in-the-google-app-engine)

Don't need to use custom runtime if you don't want to.